# How to zoom out image 30 % in UIScrollview iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want to zoom  out image to 30 % or current image? i am using UIImageView inside UIScrollView?. what will be the value of

```
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = maxScale;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
```

I don't have to scroll image.Just zoom out by 30 % automatically. How to do that ? do i need to implement delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to implement following `UIScrollView` `delegate`

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
UIView *view = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
return view;
}
```

set minimum and maximum zoom scale as

```
[_scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.3];
[_scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
```

and if you want to set directly to 30% of original then use below where you have completely set every thing,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [scrollView setZoomScale:0.3];
    }];
```

The animation here will give a smooth transaction on zooming

Comment: i am using content mode .center. not look any difference.